# Nested pipeline variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, nested, pipeline

I have the following directory tree composed of a root directory containing 10 subdirectories, and 1 file in each subdirectory.

root/

- dir1/

  - file
- dir2/

  - file
- ...
- dir10/

  - file

I would like to edit the content of the files recursively, replacing a string "str1" by "str2". I issued the following command in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | foreach {(get-content $_/file) -replace "str1", "str2" | set-content $_/file}
```

And it worked like a charm, but I still do not understand how. I use a pipeline in the foreach loop, but the following call to $_ still refers to the pipeline outside the foreach loop. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your command *did work*, is the problem.

The `-Directory` switch of `Get-ChildItem` makes it only return directories, not files.  If you want to return files, use the `-File` switch.

Next up, if you have a list of items from `Get-ChildItem`, those give you a `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` object.  We can provide those directly to the `Get-Content` command to read the file into a string.

From a string, you can call any of [the general operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7) PowerShell offers, including the string replace operator, `-Replace`.  The output of this can be piped over to `Set-Content` and used to update or append content to an existing file.

```
Get-ChildItem | foreach {
    (get-content $_) -replace "str1", "str2" | Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Note the only real change here is that I removed `-Directory` from `Get-ChildItem`, and then fixed the syntax on the `$PSItem` (the official name for the present variable in a `forEach` loop, often written as `$_`).

The reason you can use the syntax I showed is that `forEach-object` gives you that special `$_` or `$PSitem` variable to use to reference `$this` in a collection.

Comment: Thanks FoxDeploy. The command did work, I checked. I used the -Directory switch because I have several files under each subdirectory, but I only want to edit one. I did not know about the special $_/$PSitem though, nor do I know about the -PassThru switch. I'll dig a bit deeper, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, you don't need the `-PassThru` switch for `Set-Content`, that just displays the changes in the console for you to verify.

Answer (score 0):

The special variable $_ is not unique for the foreach loop.
It is a placeholder for the object being passed through the pipe line.

This article: [POWERSHELL POWER LESSON: THIS IS NO ORDINARY VARIABLE](http://techgenix.com/dollar-sign-underscore-dot/) goes into more detail about the $_ variable.

Comment: I know that, that's the reason why I am surprised that the command I issued worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Both `$_` and the `|` are inside the foreach loop in the curly braces `{ }` or script block.